# How can you see the reason a question was closed before migrating to another site?

Tags: support

This question, [Should I write 'content of the file' or 'content in the file' ?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84558/should-i-write-content-of-the-file-or-content-in-the-file), was migrated from ELU to ELL.

Checking the the revision history of the original question on ELU, [Which sentence is correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/313919/revisions), it shows as

> Post Closed as "off-topic" by ...
>   Post Migrated Away to ell.stackexchange.com

What was the reason it was closed on ELU?

Comment: Since it was migrated, it's almost certain the reason selected was "off-topic because it belongs on another SE site"; namely, this one. As for the reason, I'm assuming it's because whether to use "of" or "in" was considered too simple a question for EL&U.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think you *can*. However, John's right that it was almost certainly a 4+ supermajority voting to migrate using the entry in the migration list.

Answer (score 1):

Since the "migrators" and close voters are the same people, the close reason is "this question should go to ELL".

Since the migration path is set up, we *are* going to see more inappropriate migrations.

Comment: I'd almost like to see a one or two point reputation deduction for every question you vote to migrate that gets rejected. There seems to be no consequences/incentives for making sure that a question is reasonably likely to be accepted by the site you're trying to migrate it to.

Comment: @Colleen I think I've seen that request before on meta.SE, but can't for the life of me find it. You can open a feature request there I guess, but don't expect much response. Out of 333 migration-related feature requests, 288 of them are not status-completed, and 255 don't have any of the [status-] tags.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes that is my concern. Other than technical difficulty of any language problem (or what you would consider the basic real differences of ELL vs. ELU subject matter), the close reasons should be similar. For the question I linked, either 'dictionary lookup needed' or 'requires more detail or context', should apply to either group equally. I can't see close reasons in ELU because I don't have rep. there, but I assume the basic ones (including 'proofreading') are the same.

Comment: @user you can see their close reasons by flagging. The two sites' close reasons are unsurprisingly similar. Migration was a wrong decision here, but it would've been awesome if the only bad migration was this case. We're gonna get lots of these in the future.

Comment: @IͶΔ Maybe someone with some pull over at ELU could remind them from time to time...

Comment: @user we have a snail vehicle [in charge of that](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/a-friendly-reminder-ell-is-not-elus-trash-can). :)